# No error on xcb_grab_key but event loop not catching (Global Hotkey)

Tags: linux, x11, xcb

I am trying to set up a global hotkey on Linux.

I had initially used x11 (`libX11.so`) however I had to do this from a thread. I tried it but the `XPendingEvent` and `XNextEvent` would eventually crash the app.

So I switched to xcb (`libxcb.so.1`). There is no errors, I even check with `xcb_request_check` however the event loop is not picking anything up. As soon as I start the loop, I get only one event which looks like this:

```
{
    response_type: 0,
    pad0: 10,
    sequence: 2,
    pad: [620, 2162688, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    full_sequence: 2
}
```

Here is my code, I actually do this in js-ctypes, but I cut down all the stuff to just show simple agnostic as possible code:

```
conn = xcb_connect(null, null);

keysyms = xcb_key_symbols_alloc(conn);

keycodesPtr = xcb_key_symbols_get_keycode(keysyms, XK_Space);

setup = xcb_get_setup(conn);

screens = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(setup);
screensCnt = screens.rem;

for (var i=0; i<screensCnt; i++) {
    rez_grab = xcb_grab_key(conn, 1, screens.data.root, XCB_MOD_MASK_ANY, keycodesPtr[0], XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC, XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC);

    rez_err = xcb_request_check(conn, rez_grab);
    // rez_err is null

    xcb_screen_next(&screens);
}

xcb_flush(conn);

// start event loop
while (true) {
    ev = xcb_poll_for_event(conn);

    console.log(ev);

    if (ev != null) {
        free(ev);
    }

    Sleep(50);
}
```

`console.log(ev)` gives me what I posted above earlier, `response_type` of `0` and then forever after that `ev` is just `null`.

Does anyone know what's up? rez_grab as a raw string is `xcb_void_cookie_t(2)`

Thanks much

Comment: I don't understant the "while (true)" what is the true value ? . Could you create a more simple working code that reproduce your problem. Sometimes just doing this guide you to the solution.

Comment: Thanks @cedlemo very much for the attention. I was just modifying the code to make it simple my real code is here - https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/master/modules/hotkey/HotkeyWorker.js#L373-L453 - it is basically an endless event loop I'm trying to create, so I know when a hotkey I specified was pressed. And I know `grab_key` so that key has no affect anywhere, except for my hotkey. Its not working though :( I based it on http://stackoverflow.com/q/14553810/1828637 - but I am in a thread so it might be different.

Comment: Have you set up the attributes for the root window? [This C program works](http://pastebin.com/eaY7ggJy).

Comment: Thanks @n.m. very much will try in just a couple hours, I hadn't tried setting attr on root window. Thanks very much for your attention! I'll report back how it goes. :)

Comment: Drats @n.m. its not working for me, did you try that code from a thread?

Comment: Nope, I'm not sure why this should matter.

Comment: Thanks I'm not sure why my thing won't work :( I do exactly the same just from a thread :( Does the grab succesfully grab your space bar?

Comment: @n.m. can you please share how I can compile your C program I tried `gcc -o grab grab.c -L/usr/X11/lib -lX11 -lstdc++` however it fails for me :(

Comment: I use `gcc -o grab grab.c  -std=gnu99 -lxcb -lxcb-keysyms`, you may have to add `-I` and/or `-L` flags but no other flags.

Comment: Hey @n.m. I made a very readable version of this here - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/3870a1e5ab341fe8604cf516ff7c93cb - do you use firefox by any chance? You can copy paste my code into scratchpad in "browser" environment and run - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oo4STWceGTM if you could take a look at this i would suuuuper greatful I need another set of eyes on this :(

Comment: Oh before running, you can open Browser Console with Ctrl + Shift + J and you can see all the stuff being logged. :) This screenshot is what it looks like for me right now- http://i.imgur.com/L1C8q2a.png

Comment: Hey @n.m. my friend compiled grab.c and it didnt work for him on debinan or ubuntu. BUT we found this other example and compiled it and it worked for him on debian, but not on Ubuntu 15.01, 14.04 or on xubuntu - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/ab95289bc45a125b2d37bd7e3572122f - we compiled it with `gcc mpkey.c -std=gnu99 -lxcb -lxcb-keysyms` after installing `sudo apt-get install x11proto-core-dev` and `apt-get install libxcb-keysyms1-dev`. Isnt xcb cross flavor? Do you know why its not working on ubuntu? Thanks so much

Comment: @n.m. figured it out at long last!! I was using `XCB_MOD_MASK_ANY` and this constant works on Debian but not on Ubuntu, which is what I was using to test. I swithced that up to use num lock, caps lock etc and now it works! :)  https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/master/modules/hotkey/HotkeyWorker.js#L347-L349 that was very very crazy i had no idea the `XCB_MOD_MASK_ANY` constant didnt work on Ubuntu - https://github.com/Noitidart/System-Hotkey/blob/master/modules/hotkey/HotkeyWorker.js#L434 your exact code i tried on ubuntu it didnt work, but worked on debian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out at long last!! Ah figured this one out! I was using `XCB_MOD_MASK_ANY` and this constant works on Debian but not on Ubuntu, which is what I was using to test. I switched that up to use num lock, caps lock etc and now it works! :)

```
ostypes.API('xcb_grab_key')(conn, 1, screens.data.contents.root, ostypes.CONST.XCB_MOD_MASK_LOCK, keycodesArr[j], ostypes.CONST.XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC, ostypes.CONST.XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC); // caps lock
ostypes.API('xcb_grab_key')(conn, 1, screens.data.contents.root, ostypes.CONST.XCB_MOD_MASK_2, keycodesArr[j], ostypes.CONST.XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC, ostypes.CONST.XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC); // num lock
ostypes.API('xcb_grab_key')(conn, 1, screens.data.contents.root, ostypes.CONST.XCB_MOD_MASK_LOCK | ostypes.CONST.XCB_MOD_MASK_2, keycodesArr[j], ostypes.CONST.XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC, ostypes.CONST.XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC); // caps lock AND num lock
```

that was very very crazy i had no idea the `XCB_MOD_MASK_ANY` constant didnt work on Ubuntu -

```
var rez_grab = ostypes.API('xcb_grab_key')(conn, 1, screens.data.contents.root, ostypes.CONST.XCB_MOD_MASK_ANY, keycodesArr[j], ostypes.CONST.XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC, ostypes.CONST.XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC);
```

I also tried @n.m's code. On ubuntu it didnt work, but worked on debian -

```
#include <xcb/xcb.h>
#define XK_LATIN1
#include <xcb/xcb_keysyms.h>
#include <X11/keysymdef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main ()
{
  xcb_connection_t *conn;

  conn = xcb_connect (NULL, NULL);

  xcb_key_symbols_t * keysyms = xcb_key_symbols_alloc(conn);

  xcb_keycode_t * keycodesPtr = xcb_key_symbols_get_keycode(keysyms, XK_space);

  const xcb_setup_t* setup = xcb_get_setup(conn);

  xcb_screen_iterator_t screens = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(setup);
  int screensCnt = screens.rem;

  for (int i=0; i<screensCnt; i++) {

      xcb_void_cookie_t rez_grab = xcb_grab_key(conn, 1, screens.data->root, XCB_MOD_MASK_ANY, keycodesPtr[0], XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC, XCB_GRAB_MODE_ASYNC);

      const static uint32_t values[] = { XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE | XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_PRESS };

      xcb_change_window_attributes (conn, screens.data->root, XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK, values);

      xcb_screen_next(&screens);
  }

  xcb_flush(conn);

  // start event loop
  while (1) {
      xcb_generic_event_t *ev = xcb_wait_for_event(conn);

      if (ev && ((ev->response_type & ~0x80) == XCB_KEY_PRESS))
      {
          xcb_key_press_event_t *kp = (xcb_key_press_event_t *)ev;
          printf ("Got key press %d\n", (int)kp->event);
      }

      if (ev != NULL) {
          free(ev);
      }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So did you manage to generate events from keys **without any modifier**? Because I'm on Ubuntu and I'm having the same problem of `XCB_MOD_MASK_ANY` not working... (But all the other mod masks, like `XCB_MOD_MASK_SHIFT`, `XCB_MOD_MASK_1` do seem to work)

Comment: @étale-cohomology Yep, I registered listeners like this - https://github.com/Noitidart/jscSystemHotkey/blob/master/shtkMainworkerSubscript.js#L262 - for no mods just pass in `XCB_NONE` which is `0`. Here are the codes I used for the various mods - https://github.com/Noitidart/jscSystemHotkey/blob/master/shtkMainworkerSubscript.js#L619 - If it works for you, please post up another question I would love to supply answer and get some points for accepted answer. :) This is a great topic on mods - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376338/xcb-keyboard-button-masks-meaning#comment28827071_19376338

Comment: @étale-cohomology the key thing to note is that caps lock and num lock are counted as modifiers. so you have to xcb_grab_key for `XCB_NONE`, then `xcb_grab_key` again for num lock `XCB_MOD_MASK_LOCK`, then `xcb_grab_key` again for caps lock `XCB_MOD_MASK_2`, and finally again for if both numlock and capslock are on `XCB_MOD_MASK_2 | XCB_MOD_MASK_LOCK`

Comment: Any update for why `XCB_MOD_MASK_ANY` doesn't work?

Comment: Found the answer - the reason why `XCB_MOD_MASK_ANY` didn't work for you is probably because that key was already grabbed somewhere:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libxcb/-/issues/57

Comment: Thanks for sharing that bam!